# Change attribute value under specified path

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I need xsl template that for specified ‘element_type’ under specified ‘path’ with attribute ‘name’ value matched to ‘old_value’ will replace ‘old_value’ with ‘new_value’

I created xsl template with proper handling for ‘element_type’, ‘old_value’, ‘new_value’ parameters. I stacked with handling ‘path’ parameter. 
Below is input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<storage name="hdd1">
    <folder name="root">
        <folder name="sub1">
            <folder name="sub1-sub">
                <file name="temp-docs"/>
                <folder name="temp-docs"/>
                <folder name="temp-pictures"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
        <folder name="sub2">
            <folder name="temp-docs">
                <folder name="inner-temp-bar"/>
            </folder>
            <folder name="temp-pictures"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="temp-docs"/>
    <folder name="temp-pictures"/>
</storage>
```

The next is designed XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="element_type"/>
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:param name="old_value"/>
    <xsl:param name="new_value"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ | * | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., $old_value)
            and local-name() = 'name'
            and name(..) = $element_type
            and ancestor::*[2]/@name = $path">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $old_value)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$new_value"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $old_value)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For input parameters:

```
'element_type' = 'folder'   
'old_value' = 'temp-'  
'new_value' = ''  
'path'= 'sub2'
```

The above XSL application to above XML result is (renamed all 'folder' element, but not 'folder' element with name="inner-temp-bar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage name="hdd1">
    <folder name="root">
        <folder name="sub1">
            <folder name="sub1-sub">
                <file name="temp-docs"/>
                <folder name="temp-docs"/>
                <folder name="temp-pictures"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
        <folder name="sub2">
            <folder name="docs">
                <folder name="inner-temp-docs"/>
            </folder>
            <folder name="pictures"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="temp-docs"/>
    <folder name="temp-pictures"/>
</storage>
```

The goal is rename all folders and subfolders under specified path, e.g:
- 'path' = 'root/sub2' will rename all 'folder' elements inside 'sub2' element;
- 'path' = 'root' will rename all 'folder' elements inside 'sub1' and 'sub2' element.
How I need to handle 'path' parameter to achieve above goal?

Comment: Your stylesheet has `version="1.0"`, yet your question is tagged as xslt-2.0. Please clarify whether you use an XSLT 2.0 processor as that make coding easier for sure.

Comment: Sorry, missprinted, updated version to xslt-2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="element_type" select="'folder'"/>
    <xsl:param name="path" select="'root/sub2'"/>
    <xsl:param name="old_value" select="'temp-'"/>
    <xsl:param name="new_value" select="''"/>

    <xsl:param name="path-tokens" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($path, '/')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[string-join(ancestor-or-self::*[position() le count($path-tokens)]/@name, '/') eq $path]//*[local-name() eq $element_type]/@name[contains(., $old_value)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., $old_value, $new_value)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```